# Redshift timestamp timezone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

What's the best practise for storing timestamp values in a timestamp column. When copying from parquet timestamps are getting converted to UTC but not with other file formats.

According to documentation Redshift stores timestamps in UTC, in that case is it advisable to convert timestamps to UTC while copying from CSV or formats other than parquet?

Would like to know what everyone is doing in their organisation and what's the best practise.

Thanks,
mc

Comment: You won't get an answer on StackOverflow to a question like "what is everyone doing". If your data has timestamps from more than one timezone, then it is advisable to store in UTC. If everything you do is always in one location, then you could choose to use that timezone instead, but also consider your future needs.

Comment: if the time zone offsets are important, then you should also consider storing the offset in another column. for instance if you're studying when your users are logging in, you might want to aggregate by local time in some cases. the offset will come in handy here

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, my tampstamp column has a single location data. @JohnRotenstein - if my data is mix of timezones, how does UTC help? Redshift column is without timezone and only copying from parquet is causing this UTC offset. If we consider my local timezone is Australia/Melbourne, Redshift offsets it by -10 hours across the column. So it is not true UTC.

Comment: I was working for a company in Australia too, but our default timezone was US west-coast (where the servers were based). This was fine until we had staff and users around the world. We were using a "timestamp without timezone" field, which was not aware of timezones, so we had to keep translating timestamps into the correct timezone. We soon learned that using UTC was the simpler alternative, since it is the default for many other systems. Or, better yet, use timezone-aware timestamps so that the database can handle all conversions. However, you will still get hit by daylight savings changes.

Comment: For some real 'opinions' on this topic, I suggest you ask at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws